# capturar valor do < option > com jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Galera tenho o seguinte `select` em html.

```
 <select name='busca' onChange='link()'>
            <option value="1">OP1</option> 
            <option value="2">OP2</option>
            <option value="3">OP3</option>
            <option value="4">OP4</option> 
        </select>
```

Preciso criar uma função em jQquey chamada `link` onde ele dele pega o valor do select e carregar um link, exemplo: `envia.php?op=1`

Alguém sabe como fazer isso?

Comment: Você poderia definir "carregar"? Você quer navegar para a URL gerada ou fazer algum tipo de requisição em background?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

É possível pelo evento [change](https://api.jquery.com/change/) do próprio jQuery obter o valor:

```js
$('select[name="busca"]').on("change",function(ev){
  var linkEnviar = "envia.php?op=" + $(this).val();
  console.log(linkEnviar);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="busca" name='busca'>
  <option value="1">OP1</option>
  <option value="2">OP2</option>
  <option value="3">OP3</option>
  <option value="4">OP4</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Lucas o seu código não funciona, quando clico e seleciono uma opção, nada acontece.

Comment: Para mim está executando: http://imgur.com/a/hcYQS

Comment: estranho eu copiei o código para uma página minha e esta dando erro. O estranho que que aqui no stack ele executa normalmente.

Comment: no meu consele fica aparecendo uns caracter estranho, cr

Comment: Se você puder compartilhar o trecho do seu código html e javascript podemos ajudar

Comment: Eu estava fazendo a seleção por id, alterei a resposta para obter por name exatamente igual ao seu caso `'select[name="busca"]'`

Comment: ok, o erro no meu console fica assim: `ReferenceError: Can't find variable: $`

Comment: olha os caracteres estranhos que aparecem https://s22.postimg.org/gltuq0old/Captura_de_Tela_2016_11_17_s_10_01_14.png

Comment: O primeiro erro é porquê ele não reconheceu o jQuery. Você está carregando onde o jQuery? Qual versão?

Comment: `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: O CDN está errado, substitua por: <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>

Comment: ok, deu certo hahahaha. Obrigado. Agora como faço para chamar o link? Tentei assim `document.location=linkEnviar;` mas não deu certo

Comment: Talvez você esteja procurando por `location.href = '/' + linkEnviar;`

Comment: deu certo muito obrigado

Comment: maravilha, de nada :)

Answer (score 7):

Coloca a lógica no jQuery e podes usar `this.value` para saber o valor do select dentro de uma callback do evento `change` assim:

```
$('select[name="busca"]').on('change', link);

function link() {
    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "envia.php",
        data: {op: this.value} // <---- aqui passas o valor
    }).done(function(msg) {
        alert(msg);
    });
}
```

Comment: acredito que a opção deva ir na própria url  @Sergio, por usar argumento no exemplo que OP postou..sugere ser um método get

Comment: @LucasCosta passei isso no objeto "data": `data: {op: this.value}`

Comment: Não ficou muito claro para mim (pelo termo "carregar") se o OP está querendo fazer uma requisição ajax ou navegar para a URL (`window.location.href`). Vamos ver pela reação dele

Comment: Agora vi que você editou :)

Answer (score 2):

Segue exemplo.
HTML:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){    
  $("#selecao").on("change", teste);
});
var teste = function(evt){
                var valorSelecionado = evt.target.value;
  console.log(evt.target.value);
            }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="selecao">
  <option value="1">Opção 1</option>
  <option value="2">Opção 2</option>
  <option value="3">Opção 3</option>
</select>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){document.getElementById("selecao").addEventListener("change", teste);}
var teste = function(evt){
                var valorSelecionado = evt.target.value;
            }
```

Comment: muito bom, era isso mesmo :)

Comment: o value do <select> é o value do <option> selecionado

Answer (score 1):

Também da para fazer com javascript puro:

```html
<select name='busca' onChange='location.href="envia.php?op="+this.value'>
            <option value="1">OP1</option> 
            <option value="2">OP2</option>
            <option value="3">OP3</option>
            <option value="4">OP4</option> 
        </select>
```