# passar o nome do formulário para jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho a seguinte função que envia um formulário:

```
function enviar_formulario() {
    document.search.submit();
}
```

Quando quero chamar a função eu faço assim:

```
        <select name='busca' onChange='enviar_formulario(search)'>
            <option value="1">ID</option>
            <option value="2">NOME</option> 
        </select>
```

E sempre que eu seleciona a opção ela envia o formulário.

Bom ela funciona, porém o `form` tem que estar com o nome de `search`.
Como faço para passar o nome do formulário a ser enviado para a função?

Exemplo:

```
enviar_formulario(nome_do_formulário_a_ser_enviado)
```

Comment: Podes mostrar o HTML do form e do botão?

Comment: Na verdade não é um botão, é um select, e quando mudo o valor ele tem que enviar o formulário. Vou colocar ele na minha pergunta.

Comment: @HugoBorges Você quer passar este código para Jquery e usar também um modo como parâmetro ?

Comment: @MauroAlexandre coloquei em JS puro porque não sei como fazer em Jquery hahahaha. Sim e isso mesmo que eu quero.

Comment: E da onde vem o nome do formulário? Pelas opções do select são campos.

Comment: então eu quero informar o nome quando chamo a função `enviar_formulario(nome_aqui)` o formular esta assim `<form name='nome_aqui'>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Com jQuery você você checar obtendo o evento [submit](https://api.jquery.com/submit/) de qualquer formulário e então o obter o *name* dele:

*HTML:*

```
<form name="form1" action="">
  <input type="text" value="Olá">
  <input type="submit" value="Go">
</form>
```

*Javascript:*

```
$("form").submit(function( event ) { 
  event.preventDefault();
  var nome = $(this).attr("name");
  alert(nome);
});
```

**JSFiddle**: https://jsfiddle.net/kwx8tyx1/

**Editado:**

Com `select` você pode fazer dessa forma:

```
<select name='busca' onChange="enviar_formulario('form1')">
     <option value="1">ID</option>
     <option value="2">NOME</option> 
</select>
```

Javascript:

```
function enviar_formulario(nome){
    $("form[name='"+ nome + "']").submit();
}
```

Comment: Creio que seria uma má prática, já que o autor está citando o código em JS puro, mas ele `taggou` Jquery, vamos ver o que o autor acha.

Comment: "passar o nome do formulário para jQuery" está no título com a tag jQuery.

Comment: Sim. Por que fica a dúvida no ar, não está muito clara. Sua questão está boa, só citei isso para que o autor pudesse ver.

Comment: obrigado pela ajuda

Answer (score 3):

Se usasses [como sugeri na outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/165941/129) aplica-se bem aqui também:

```
$('select[name="busca"]').on('change', enviar_formulario);

function enviar_formulario() {
    document[this.name].submit();
}
```

Ou simplesmente ir procurar a `form` onde esse select está por hieraquia do DOM:

```
$('select[name="busca"]').on('change', function() {
    $(this).closest('form').submit();
}
```

Comment: +1 pelo closest

Comment: obrigado pela ajuda

Answer (score 0):

Tente fazer a função assim:

```
function enviar_formulario(nome) {
  document[nome].submit();
}
```

---

### UPDATE

Pensei que funcionaria assim para não mudar muito do que você ja usa.

Tente assim então:

```
document.querySelector('select[name=busca]').addEventListener('change', function() {
  enviarFormulario('form'+this.value);
});

function enviarFormulario(nome) {
  form = document.querySelector('form[name='+nome+']');
  if(form) {
    form.submit();
  }
}
```

Comment: deu esse erro no console `TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'document[nome].submit')`

Comment: editei minha questão, depois vc da uma olhada lá por favor