# Diferença entre a sintaxe para se declarar uma função

Tags: javascript, jquery, funções, sintaxe

Lendo [esta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/165939/20615), eu percebi formas diferentes de *chamar* uma função utilizando o jQuery.

A primeira forma seria esta:

```
$('#dois').on("click", testar);

function testar() {
  console.log('Teste Dois');
}
```

E a segunda, é esta:

```
$('#um').on("click", function() {
  console.log('Teste Um');
});
```

Existe diferença entre essas duas formas, além da *sintaxe*?

Abaixo está um pequeno exemplo para ajudar o entendimento.

```js
$('#um').on("click", function() {
  console.log('Teste Um');
});


$('#dois').on("click", testar);

function testar() {
  console.log('Teste Dois');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="um">Teste 1</button>

<br/>
<br/>
<button id="dois">Teste 2</button>
```

Comment: Creio que não, até por que no jquery o segundo parâmetro é uma call para uma função. Então fazer `$('#dois').on("click", testar);` seria o mesmo de `$('#dois').on("click", function(){ //... } );`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A diferença maior que vejo é nas declarações.

Na opção 1, você usou uma função, e na opção 2, uma função anônima.

Creio que a principal diferença nesse caso é que, com a função declarada, para depois ser passada por `callback`, você pode repeti-la para eventos diferentes (quantas vezes quiser), sem repetir código desnecessário.

Exemplo:

```
$('#dois').on("click", testar);
$(document).on("click", ".botao-dinamico", testar);

function testar() {
  console.log('Teste Dois');
}
```

Como já foi citado, muitas pessoas não sabem que é possível fazer tal operação em jQuery e acabam caindo no problema a seguir:

```
$('#dois').on("click", function () {
       console.log('Teste Dois');
});

$(document).on("click", ".botao-dinamico", function () {
       console.log('Teste Dois');
});
```

Note que o segundo exemplo trata-se de uma *complicação desnecessária*. Sendo assim, fico com a minha primeira opção.

É claro que temos que relembrar que o exemplo está bem simples nesse caso. Você poderia ter ganhos maiores em casos onde precisasse de uma função mais complexa.

Por exemplo, a sua função `testar` poderia estar utilizando `this` ou então alguns parâmetros específicos (como `event`) normalmente, pois no final isso não vai fazer diferença alguma, já que tudo que o jQuery precisa é um callback.

**Bônus**

Se você quiser considerar apenas como curiosidade essa informação que passarei a seguir, ainda é possível utilizar uma função anônima nomeada:

```
$('#um').on("click", function onClick() {
  console.log(onClick);
});
```

No caso específico, ela não vai entrar no escopo global ou local do Javascript, mas vai estar acessível apenas da própria função anônima.

Comment: Eu pensei que seria isso mesmo. Mas queria ter certeza, já que quase nunca vejo alguém usar uma função, e sim criando uma para cada evento.

Comment: +1 pelo bônus! :)

Answer (score 11):

JavaScript tem umas idiossincrasias e pode ter me escapado alguma coisa, mas em condições normais não há diferença no uso. Ambas executarão da mesma forma. Uma é anônima e declarada *inline* na chamada e a outra é nomeada e previamente definida em algum lugar.

Acredito que muita gente não use uma função previamente definida porque não sabem usar. É a mesma coisa das pessoas não entenderem a utilidade da variável, a pessoa não sabe quando usar uma ou quando usar o valor *inline*. Acho que falta entendimento da linguagem. No fundo uma função nomeada é como se fosse uma variável, e uma função anônima é como se fosse o valor.

Mas também é razoável inferir que em muitos casos criar uma função anônima ali na chamada mesmo é o mais adequado. Na maior parte das vezes você só precisa dessa função ali mesmo, não tem porque defini-la em outro lugar.

Eu já fazerem:

```
$('#dois').on("click", function() {
    testar();
});

function testar() {
    console.log('Teste Dois');
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Function/ClickjQuery.js).

Aí não dá, né? Tecnicamente dá, e talvez tenha um motivo semântico, mas quase sempre é um erro porque a pessoa não entende o que está fazendo.

O uso não faz diferença para o jQuery.

Não entrei no mérito de usar a declaração da função como identificador de função ou como variável. Isso pode ser observado em [Qual a diferença entre as funções var name = function() e function name()?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/13364/101). Aí tem uma pequena diferença explicada lá na pergunta. Isso está demonstrado na resposta do Guilherme Nascimento.

Comment: *Acredito que muita gente não use uma função previamente definida porque não sabem usar.*... Ganhou meu +1 por causa desse comentário.

Comment: Se essa parte de *não saber usar* fosse apenas para JS eu ficaria feliz. Porém, acontece em qualquer linguagem. Mas, boa resposta

Comment: @Randrade sim, o pessoal não sabe coisas bem básicas de programação, é tudo na base da receita de bolo sem sequer entender uma vírgula do que está ali.

Comment: Como seria o uso de uma função previamente definida ?

Comment: @MagicHat da forma como está mostrada na pergunta. O primeiro exemplo mostra isso.

Comment: Acho engraçado ela ser chamada de "previamente definida" se ela vem após a chamada, essa leitura do bloco, qual o tema que oferece informações sobre processo...

Comment: @MagicHat Mas ela é previamente definida, se não fosse, como poderia ser usada? O fato de você escrever fora de ordem não significa que o código seja interpretado assim.

Comment: É justamente essa informação que procuro, sobre como a ordem da interpretação do código acontece, em que momento os parâmetros são solicitados e tals, sabe algum tema que aborde isso, creio que deve ser os compiladores, mas só de olhar a capa já dá tontura... Se tiver uma questão falando sobre isso, agradeço o link..

Comment: @MagicHat é sobre compiladores, no caso o compilador do JS tem dois passos, ele compila as declarações globais e depois compila os corpos dos seus membros.

Comment: Estava procurando este link, agora que o adicionou a sua resposta +1, acho que este é o ponto principal, ou sej não é algo sobre jQuery, mas sim sobre a linguagem js

Answer (score 7):

Na prática, para o teu exemplo, são semelhantes, fazem a mesma coisa.

A vantagem de usar `$('#dois').on("click", testar);` é caso haja mais auscultadores de evento que também devam chamar a função `testar`, ou em casos de programação orientada a objetos onde muitas vezes se passa o método que deve ser executado, em vez de expor a função no local.

De resto o caso `$('#dois').on("click", testar);` usa uma função nomeada, ou função com nome; e o outro exemplo usa uma função anónima.

Answer (score 4):

Apenas um adendo para explicar sobre a diferença de outras funções de qualquer tipo contra:

```
function testar() {
    console.log('Teste Dois');
}
```

Diferente da maneira citada acima, praticamente quase todas as outras formas serão funções anonimas, por exemplo, se fizer isto sempre será uma função anonima:

```
var foo = function () { /** Algo aqui **/ };

document.getElementById("meuId").onclick = foo;
```

Mesmo que salva em uma variável.

Se tentar chamar assim vai reconhecer, isso devido a ordem da declaração:

```js
var foo;

document.getElementById("meuId").onclick = foo;

foo = function () {
    alert("Oi");
};
```

```html
<button id="meuId">Teste</button>
```

Mas se fizer isto irá funcionar, mesmo que a função venha depois:

```js
document.getElementById("meuId").onclick = foo;

function foo() {
    alert("Oi");
}
```

```html
<button id="meuId">Teste</button>
```

Comment: Gostei de ter mostrado como isso é "realmente feito". +1