# Diferença entre função e funçao anonima em JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Olá tenho dúvida de qual seria a diferença entre `função` e `função anônima`, segue o exemplo de código das duas possibilidades .

> FUNÇÃO 1

```
titulo.addEventListener("click"), function(){
  console.log("Olá");
}
```

> FUNÇÃO 2

```
titulo.addEventListener("click", mostraMensagem);
function mostraMensagem(){
  console.log("Olá");
}
```

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/165984/diferen%C3%A7a-entre-a-sintaxe-para-se-declarar-uma-fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bom a única diferença sintática, é que a função anônima não tem um nome declarado.
Mas existe diferença no uso, uma vez que uma função anônima não possui nome, ela não pode ser chamada várias vezes em um código, ela é utilizada mais em `callbacks` de outras funções

Funções anônimas são como ,scripts a serem executados que são escritos **ONDE** eles serão executados, 
Já as funções são trechos de códigos isolados que são chamados quantas vezes necessário

exemplos usabilidade:

**FUNÇÃO ANÔNIMA:**

```
setTimeout(function() {
   console.log('código executado na função anônima')
},300);
```

neste caso a função anônima não é uma declaração de uma função que será usada depois, e sim um código a ser executado !

Comment: Os exemplos devem ser copiados para a resposta. O link poderá não existir mais no futuro.

Comment: Claro. Já vou mover os exemplos

Comment: Quando você cria uma [função anônima com uma variável](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions#Constructor_vs._declaration_vs._expression) `const myVar = function() { ... }`, ela poderá ser utilizada varias vezes em um código.